# algebra - Solve given innequality

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

I am having problems understanding how to solve: $$ x^2 -5x \geqslant 0 $$
Any help would be much appreciated as I have been stuck on this question for quite some time.

Comment: @SergioSarmiento how do you create greater / equal to sign? or link to syntax, formatting plz!

Comment: Assume $x^2 - 5x = f(x)$, you just have to find a set of $x$-values which will always give you a result $f(x)$ which is bigger than or equal to zero.

Comment: just type \geqslant :)

Comment: @foo you can also type "\ge"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

$$x^2-5x \ge 0 \iff x(x-5)\ge 0$$

Then look when $x \ge 0$ **and** $(x-5) \ge 0$ *or* $x \le 0$ **and** $(x-5) \le 0$ (why this?)

Other Hint:

The graph of $x^2 -5x$ looks like this:

[image]

Comment: @foo you are welcome :-)